# How to detect that the current request is an authentication callback?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application, auth0

I have a single-page JavaScript application and I'm using the Auth0 service for signup/login.

I have integrated the Lock widget and I'm saving a string to `localStorage` after a user is authenticated, like so:

```
lock.on("authenticated", function(authResult) 
{
    localStorage.setItem('login', authResult.idToken);
}
```

The problem is that when Auth0 redirects them back to my application after logging in, the `authenticated` event is fired only after page loaded, but by that time, I've already done the check to see if the `localStorage` string is set (which it is not); therefore, the user just keeps getting asked to login again:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('login') == undefined)
{
   lock.show(function(err, profile, token) 
   {
       // ...
   }
}
```

I tried to see if there was anything special passed in to the page after a callback - but the referrer isn't always there.

If I don't automatically prompt the user to login, but instead show a login button - the `authenticated` event never fires for some reason.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided you seem to be using Lock in redirect mode and if that's the case you can use the [`hash_parsed` event](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/api#on-) as a way to know if Lock found a response that it will process.

> Every time a new Auth0Lock object is initialized in redirect mode (the default), it will attempt to parse the hash part of the URL, looking for the result of a login attempt. After that, **this event will be emitted with `null` if it couldn't find anything in the hash**. It will be emitted with the same argument as the `authenticated` event after a successful login or with the same argument as `authorization_error` if something went wrong.

Leveraging this event you could do the following:

1. Subscribe to the `hash_parsed` event:
2. If `hash_parsed` is emitted with `null` and `localStorage` has no indication the user already logged in then redirect to login.
3. If `hash_parsed` is emitted with a non-null value that either the `authenticated` or `authorization_error` will be emitted and you can react accordingly.

Some sample code:

```
lock.on("hash_parsed", function (response) {
    if (!response && !localStorage.getItem('login')) {
        // Redirect to the login screen
    } else {
        // Either the user is already logged in or an authentication
        // response will be processed by Lock so don't trigger
        // an automatic redirect to login screen
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Joao.  I tried this sample code, but it still ends up in an endless loop of asking for login.  After I login, it reloads the page with a ?code= parameter, but it does not get processed properly or authenticated.

Comment: The appearance of `?code=` suggests that you're using the OAuth2 authorization code grant which is meant for server-side web application to process. If you want a SPA where Lock processes the authentication response, you'll need to use the implicit grant so that the response is delivered in the hash fragment of the URL (`#...`).